# mysql method to replace valid email address/s in a text field with dummy email addresses

Tags: mysql

I am looking for the most efficient method to find an email address in a text field in a mysql database and replace all instances with dummy email addresses for all records.

I found a excellent MS sql version on stackoverflow that looks like it would have done the job:
update myTable set
Company = stuff(Company,
patindex(Company,'%[ ,&]Co[^A-Za-z-]%'+3,1,'.')

The above will find all "Co" text and replace with "Co.", within the Company field.

BUT this does not translate easily to mysql and I am having difficulty finding the mysql equivalent. A little help please!

This field is a text field that contains valid user email addresses. I would like to clear out the valid email addresses and replace with dummy email addresses eg email@email.com.

Comment: What is the purpose of this strange modification?

Comment: The field contains *nothing but* email addresses or has other text?

Comment: The purpose is to purge rows in a table of client email addresses and to replace them with dummy email data. It is to protect client details.

Comment: The field does include additional text along with the email addresses.